# Using Javascript to verify two emails are the same before submitting form

Tags: javascript, html

I need to verify the email fields are the same before submitting the form.
I have submitted the full html in the codepen with comments below but I am most unsure about the function and the syntax of how to prevent the form from submitting and alerting the user to make sure the emails match.

I tried the following code, I expected the browser to send an alert to the user that they need to "make sure the emails match" if they input emails that are different, what resulted was when submitting the form and the emails don't match it does not alert the user and prevent the form from submitting

```js
const element = document.getElementById("submit");
element.addEventListener("click", checkEmail);

function checkEmail() {
  const email = document.getElementById("first");
  const confirm = document.getElementById("confirm");

  if (email === confirm) {
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Make sure the emails match");
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="http://northcarolinatest.atwebpages.com/Form.html" method="POST" id="form" autocomplete="off">
  <label for="first">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="first" id="first" placeholder="John" required>
  <br>
  <label for="last">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="last" id="last" placeholder="Doe" required>
  <br>
  <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="JohnDoe@gmail.com" required>
  <br>

  <label for="confirm">Confirm Email:</label>
  <input type="email" name="confirm" id="confirm" placeholder="JohnDoe@gmail.com" required>
  <br>

  <label for="question">Question:</label>
  <input type="text" name="question" id="question" placeholder="Where do I go to register to vote?" width="500px" required>
  <br>
  <input type="Submit">
</form>
```

https://codepen.io/16nicolha/pen/MWLKdqz

Comment: Did you read the console errors? Also please post the minimum html here, not in a separate link

Comment: You are not comparing the **values** but the **elements** themselves, which will never be equal to one another. Try `const email = document.getElementById("first").value;` etc.

Comment: I updated the post to have the html. The only error I see is that the form element in the html should have the autocomplete attribute.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is intercept the `submit` event of `<form>`, not some strange button:

```
function checkEmail(event) {
  // your code
}

document.querySelector("#form").addEventListener("submit", checkEmail)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use standard HTML5 form usage...

```js
const
  myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form-id')
, errMsg = { email_confirm : `emails doesn't matches the same` }
, setError = elm =>
    {
    elm.setCustomValidity( errMsg[elm.name]);
    elm.oninput =_=>
      {
      elm.setCustomValidity(''); // clear error message
      elm.oninput = null;        // self remove setError assignation
      }
    };

myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  if ( myForm.email_confirm.value !== myForm.email_address.value )
    {
    setError( myForm.email_confirm );
    myForm.reportValidity();
    return false
    }
  }
```

```css
label {
  display   : block;
  margin    : .6rem 0;
  font-size : .8rem;
  }
label > input {
  display   : block;
  font-size : 1.2rem;
  width     : 12rem;
  }
input[name="Question"] {
  width     : 40em; 
  }
button {
  width: 6em;
  }
```

```html
<form action="" id="my-form-id">
  <label> 
    First Name:
    <input type="text" required name="first_name" placeholder="John" >
  </label>
  <label>
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" required name="last_name" placeholder="Doe" >
  </label>
  <label>
    Email:    
    <input type="email" required name="email_address"  placeholder="JohnDoe@gmail.com" >
  </label>
  <label>
    Email (confirm):    
    <input type="email" required name="email_confirm"  placeholder="JohnDoe@gmail.com" >
  </label>
  <label>
    Question: 
    <input type="text"  required name="Question" placeholder="Where do I go to register to vote?" >
  </label>

  <button>Submit</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

As [@Đinh Carabus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77384459/using-javascript-to-verify-two-emails-are-the-same-before-submitting-form#comment136423448_77384459) said, you are comparing two elements denoted by these:

```js
const email = document.getElementById("first");
const confirm = document.getElementById("confirm");
```

You must get their values first before you compare them lest, a mismatch will happen.

You also need to intercept the form's submit event as [@Tachibana Shin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77384491/7619826) said.

Here's what your JS code should be:

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form");
form.addEventListener("click", checkEmail);

function checkEmail(event) {
    const email = document.getElementById("first").value;
    const confirm = document.getElementById("confirm").value;

    if (email === confirm) {
        document.getElementById("form").submit();
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Make sure the emails match");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Add event listener to form to listen for the submit event.
- Add `event` to listener function since you reference that.
- Add a `focusout` and a custom `confirm-email` event to the `confirm` element then we can trigger that to set the message in each case.
- Use correct ID `.getElementById("email")` not `first`  IF you want to validate the name for some content that can also be done but not part of the question of comparing emails.
- Form validation reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation
- Compare the input values not the elements.
- Validate the email address, let's use the pattern on the elements: [How can I validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/125981) as a starting place
- Set validation messages for required
- Put some CSS around the valid fields and did some formatting and added a validation message for each field.

```js
const element = document.getElementById("form")
  .querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
element.addEventListener("click", checkEmail);
const confirm = document.getElementById("confirm");
confirm.addEventListener("focusout", validateEmail);
confirm.addEventListener("confirm-email", validateEmail);

function validateEmail(event) {
  const confirm = this;
  const myForm = this.closest('form');
  const email = myForm.querySelector("#email");
  const invalidMsg = "Must match email";
  const emailsMatch = email.value === confirm.value;
  confirm.setCustomValidity(emailsMatch ? "" : invalidMsg);
  confirm.closest('.input-group').querySelector('.validation-message').textContent = emailsMatch ? "" : invalidMsg;
}

function checkEmail(event) {
  const myForm = this.closest('form');
  const email = document.getElementById("email");
  const confirm = document.getElementById("confirm");
  confirm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {
    'bubbles': true
  }));
  if (!confirm.checkValidity()) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  width: 8em;
}

.input-group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "label inputfld" ". validation";
  gap: 0.25em;
}

.input-group .validation-message {
  grid-area: validation;
  color: #FF0000;
}

.input-group label {
  grid-area: label;
}

.input-group input {
  grid-area: inputfld;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.input-group input:invalid {
  border-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px red;
}

.input-group input:required {
  border-style: dashed;
}

.input-group input:valid {
  border-color: black;
  box-shadow: none;
}


}
.input-group input:valid+.validation-message {
  display: none;
}
.input-group input:valid:focus {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: #00ff0010;
}
.input-group input:invalid:focus {
  background-color: #FF000010;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: black;
}
.input-group input:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #FF000020;
}
.input-group input:invalid+.validation-message::after {
  content: ' - Invalid ';
}
.input-group input:invalid:required+.validation-message::before {
  content: ' Required ';
}
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"] {
  width: 50ch;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13ch;
  text-align: end;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<form action="http://northcarolinatest.atwebpages.com/Form.html" method="POST" id="form">
  <div class="input-group">
    <label for="first">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="first" id="first" placeholder="John" required>
    <div class="validation-message"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label for="last">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="last" id="last" placeholder="Doe" required>
    <div class="validation-message"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" minlength="6" placeholder="JohnDoe@example.com" required pattern='(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&' *+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&
      '*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])'>
    <div class="validation-message"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label for="confirm">Confirm Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="confirm" id="confirm" placeholder="JohnDoe@example.com" required pattern='(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&' *+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&
      '*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])'>
    <div class="validation-message"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">

    <label for="question">Question:</label>
    <input type="text" name="question" id="question" placeholder="Where do I go to register to vote?" required>
    <div class="validation-message"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="Submit">
</form>
```