# Javascript mail form validator

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm testing a javascript code to validate an email form with confirmation email. When I enter a confirmation email, its field remains in "success" mode even if I insert only one character equal to that of the email field, regardless of whether the regular expression is respected. I would like to achieve that if the email field is invalid, the confirmation email field must not go to "success" mode but wait for email validation to continue. Thanks for your help.

HTML

```
<form id="signup" class="form">
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="mail">Mail:</label>
        <input type="mail" name="mail" id="mail" autocomplete="off">
        <small></small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="confirm-mail">Confirm Mail:</label>
        <div class="form-field input-group">
            <input type="mail" name="confirm-mail" id="confirm-mail" autocomplete="off">
            <small></small>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Sign Up">
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
const mail = document.querySelector('#mail');
const confirmMail = document.querySelector('#confirm-mail');
const form = document.querySelector('#signup');

//shows error message
const showError = (input, message) => {
    // get the form-field element
    const formField = input.parentElement;
    // add the error class
    formField.classList.remove('success');
    formField.classList.add('error');

    // show the error message
    const error = formField.querySelector('small');
    error.textContent = message;
};

//shows success message
const showSuccess = (input) => {
    // get the form-field element
    const formField = input.parentElement;

    // remove the error class
    formField.classList.remove('error');
    formField.classList.add('success');

    // hide the error message
    const error = formField.querySelector('small');
    error.textContent = '';
};

//checks input field
const isRequired = value => value === '' ? false : true;

//checks email is valid
const isMailValid = (mail) => {
    const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(mail);
};

//validate email field
const checkMail = () => {
    let valid = false;
    const mailVal = mail.value.trim();
    if (!isRequired(mailVal)) {
        showError(mail, 'Email cannot be blank.');
    } else if (!isMailValid(mailVal)) {
        showError(mail, 'Email is not valid.')
    } else {
        showSuccess(mail);
        valid = true;
    }
    return valid;
};

//validate confirm password
const checkConfirmMail = () => {
    let valid = false;
    // check confirm password
    const confirmMailVal = confirmMail.value.trim();
    const mailVal = mail.value.trim();

    if (!isRequired(confirmMailVal)) {
        showError(confirmMail, 'Confirm Password is required');
    } else if (mailVal !== confirmMailVal) {
        showError(confirmMail, 'Confirm Password does not match');
    } else {
        showSuccess(confirmMail);
        valid = true;
    }

    return valid;
};

//modifying submit event handler
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    // prevent the form from submitting
    e.preventDefault();

    // validate forms
    let isMailValid = checkMail(),
        isConfirmMailValid = checkConfirmMail();

    let isFormValid = isMailValid &&
        isConfirmMailValid;

    // submit to the server if the form is valid
    if (isFormValid) {

    }
});
```

With this code, if I enter any same character in the email and email confirmation fields, the email confirmation field remains valid and it shouldn't be that way.

Comment: Not a direct answer but there is no real need to re-implement email validation. Especially doing it in a way to render valid emails invalid. Just use the `<input type="email"` regular HTML validation: https://jsbin.com/dosowoqazo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: you didn't need to write so much code, just use the real `type="email"` and the `required` property.

Comment: This code as a starting point for also checking the password and confirming the password. Drop-down section when conditions are met (with check mark for each valid field).

Comment: @mauror76 you're still reimplementing the wheel here. And incorrectly. The email validation you have is wrong. The `isRequiured` doesn't check whether something is required but rather it checks whether something has content. Moreover, this won't necessarily work on all devices - mobile browsers or others are going to be trying to use the default validation to provide information to users. Consider for example sight impaired users trying to use a screen reader and your validation not working with accessibility tools and guidelines.

Comment: You *can* have additional validation logic like listing all conditions but you don't have to completely reinvent and circumvent the default validation. I'd say that if *you* were able to write flawless validation logic that covers all considerations including accessibility, usability, and correctness, among others, you wouldn't have needed to ask this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77384459/using-javascript-to-verify-two-emails-are-the-same-before-submitting-form/77384583#77384583

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not validating the conformation email the same way you are validating the email. You are verifying that the email itself is an email, however you are not with the conformation email. Simply edit your function(s) to check also validate the conformation email.

Comment: I had already tested your solution, obviously it works. I would like the control to be limited only to email equals confirmation email, avoiding adding a regular expression also for confirmation email.

Comment: Consider creating a component that is reusable and validates itself instead. You'll also be able to use it in other parts of your application. Or, you could create a helper function that accepts input element(s) as arguments, and returns true or false indicating valid or invalid.

Answer (score -1):

return /^[a-z0-9.@]*$/.test(mail)

Comment: That will falsely claim ***A LOT OF*** valid emails as invalid. Just a few examples: emails written with capital letters, emails with underscores, emails with dashes, emails with a plus sign. And these are just the most common ones that it fails to validate.